# Ansible - Get current loop count when iterating over hosts

Tags: ansible

It this possible to get current for loop counter when using ansible and iterating over hosts provided?

```
- name: Debug me
  hosts: [1.2.3.4, 1.3.4.5]
  user: root
  tasks:
      - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      - debug: msg="{{ forloop.counter }}" # ??
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not actually a loop in ansible, but I think you want:

```
- name: Debug me
  hosts: [1.2.3.4, 1.3.4.5]
  user: root
  tasks:
      - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      - debug: msg="{{ play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```